# PHP: is it safe to deserialize a file directly into an object?

Tags: php, class, object, serialization, variable-assignment

In my PHP code, I create a 'session' object that stores user type, auth etc. (although no password in any form). Then I serialize this object into the $_SESSION var:

```
$_SESSION['sess_data'] = serialize($session);
```

when I need to authenticate the user, I do this:

```
$session = unserialize($_SESSION['sess_data']);
```

It looks very unsafe to me though. How can I improve it? Would some method as get_class() suffice? Thanks

Comment: Why do you think this is unsafe? It's data set by you, which can not be changed from oustide your host's scripts, and is reinstantiated by you... sounds pretty safe to me (except for session-hijacking issues of course, but that has nothing to do with your code)

Comment: What's the point of serializing your object to session?

Comment: There might be plenty other occasions when you would need to serialize object into session, but authenticating an user is not one of them. You should reconsider your user auth logic

Comment: I thought sometimes $_SESSION could be saved on client side. In any way I would like to have a safe code independently by the environment. If it cannot be the case, let us say for the sake of curiosity, how could I implement it safely using $_COOKIE instead of sessions?

Comment: $_COOKIES for authenticating on the other hand are maybe the unsafiest way you can do. While sessions are stored on the server's file system, and if explicitly anything else is said, only the PHPSESSID cookie is stored on the client computer, cookies are stored purely on clients computer and your serialized object could be seen by the user.

Comment: @RoyalBg the session object contains the user nick and temporary auth token that gets compared against the values in the db. Is it unsafer than storing their straight values? If so, why? Thanks

Comment: @sowdust I would just assign the default values of userid, token, etc to session variables rather than passing whole object into session. Serialization ain't no magical weapon that's safer than plain text. It's just for transmitting data. If you are worried so much about the values in the session, you can use some unreversable hash to encrypt them. However, I would not send any whole object to the user, because I will expose my objects code to them. And also one day when I make some database injection into the User's class constructor, the dump of the object will contain my db pass..

Comment: Long story short, by sending the whole object, you do send more information through sessions than needed

Comment: all right, that's very clear, thank you very much for the help